# Get data type by ID

Tags: oracle

I was looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1087180/1394393) for checking the data type of a value. It's quite handy and spits out something that looks kind of like this:

```
Typ=1 Len=12: 48,48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,49
```

The part that bugs me is that `Typ=#` part. I can look up what it means in [the table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96540/sql_elements2a.htm#45504) mentioned by the documentation, but as that's a web page, I can't *query* it on the fly.

I can pretty easily parse the number out of that output:

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_REPLACE('Typ=1 Len=12: 48,48,48,48,48,48,49,49,49,49,49,49', 'Typ=([0-9]+).*', '\1')) AS TYPE_ID FROM DUAL
```

But is there anywhere I can query what type that ID number goes with? I'd like to `JOIN` the type name to this dump output.

Answer (score 0):

The typecodes of built-in types are hidden in the dictionary views, but you can query the dictionary directly and find the type based on the OID:

```
select
  type_name
from
  dba_types dt
  join sys.type$ t on t.tvoid = dt.type_oid
where
  t.typecode = 1
;

NAME
----------
VARCHAR
```